# How to get values from jquery range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using ui jquery slider, but i'm not able to get the value.

```js
$("#ex1").slider({
  value: 1400,
  min: 1400,
  max: 12000,
  step: 20,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#slider-value").html(ui.value);
  }
});
$("#slider-value").html($('#ex1').slider('value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="range" data-slider-min="1400" data-slider-max="12000" data-slider-step="20" data-slider-value="0" /><b class="price-left">
<span id="slider-value"></span>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because you're instantiating the `slider()` on a `input type="range"` element. It should be used with a plain `div`. Change that and the rest of your code works fine:

```js
$("#ex1").slider({
  value: 1400,
  min: 1400,
  max: 12000,
  step: 20,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#slider-value").html(ui.value);
  }
});
$("#slider-value").html($('#ex1').slider('value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<div id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' data-slider-min="1400" data-slider-max="12000" data-slider-step="20" data-slider-value="0"></div>
<span id="slider-value"></span>
```

The slider [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) has full explanations of all other methods and properties you can use.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#ex1').slider("option", "value");
```

You can try this one (y)